# GNU Screen switch from vertical split to horizontal and back

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm using a recent version of GNU Screen, supporting vertical splits.

Once I have split a window in 2, how can I switch so that they are both dividing the whole region in half horizontally versus vertical?

I need to change to horizontal in order to copy some text with mouse from one window without the visual selection overflowing and grabbing text from the other window.

Then I would need to switch back again to a vertical split from horizontal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GNU `screen` doesn't come with any layouts predefined, so you need to roll your own. Here is what I've added to my ~/.screenrc :

```
# define layouts
layout new 'horizontal'
split
layout new 'vertical'
split -v
layout new  'main' 

# bind control sequences for new layouts
bind V layout select 'vertical'
bind H layout select 'horizontal'
bind ' ' layout next # <- actually means Ctrl-a + Space
```

With this it's possible to switch layouts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> | <kbd>V</kbd> | <kbd>H</kbd>.

(Actually, all control sequences start with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> by default, so I'll omit it from now on.)

This solution  is not ideal - after starting a screen session you initially have to *tediously* focus on each 'region' (parts of a layout) with <kbd>TAB</kbd>, and attach a process (`man screen` of all places insists on calling them 'windows' ) with <kbd>n</kbd>|<kbd>p</kbd>|<kbd>0-9</kbd>|<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or a different method of your choice.

I imagine you'll want to detach instead of killing when possible.

... and this should hopefully cover your use case. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the revised solution. As you can write such a solution for screen but prefer tmux, it's time for me to check it out!

Comment: just as an update - I did move to `tmux` shortly after this and never missed `screen` at all :)

Comment: I looked ages for the vertical split: `split -v`, thanks a lot!